# java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi

I have had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645208/java-rmi-nosuchobjectexception-no-such-object-in-table), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501873/java-rmi-nosuchobjectexception-on-linux) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629466/rmi-object-not-getting-refreshed) however I have absolutely no idea why I am coming across this error.

I am of the opinion that I have strong references (code at end of post), I am not explicitly calling GC (not that that particular method does much) and yet I just **cannot** boot this damn RMI server.

It should be noted I am extremely new to RMI. I have read the Oracle trail, that didn't work. Tried another tutorial, same problem. In fact, no matter how I approach this, I cannot get past this ObjectNotFoundException.

Now I know that this means the object no longer exists, but **why** doesn't it exist... I have a static reference to it in the main class, the VM is seriously misbehaving if it is doing this.

Running Arch Linux, oracle's VM and Eclipse kepler.

```
package engine;
import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import service.Service;

public class Main { 

private static Service stub;
private static Service engine;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "file:///home/jameshey/git/MicroSense/release/conf/rmisecurity.policy");
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        }
        try {
            String name = "HelloWorldService";
            engine = new ServiceEngine();
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(1099);
            stub = (Service) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(engine, 1099);
            registry.bind(name, stub);
            System.out.println("ServiceEngine bound");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("ServiceEngine exception:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried pretty much every forum solution I can find. I have tried no statics and combinations of which variables are static. Completely stumped.

The Stack Trace of the Exception is:

```
ServiceEngine exception:
java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:275)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:252)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:378)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(Unknown Source)
at engine.Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocateRegistry.getRegistry() doesn't create a Registry. It just creates a stub that may or may not actually work, depending on whether the Registry is running. Change it to createRegistry(). Make the Registry variable static in the server.

Comment: Yeah, turns out that all of the tutorials are silly. A colleague of mine eventually managed to point this out to me

Comment: *All* of them? Which ones do mean?

Comment: The oracle ones contain the problem with LocateRegistry.getRegistry(). Sadly I don't remember the rest of the sites I investigated